# Modem Manager Gui breaks after first time

Tags: usb-modem, segmentation-fault, modem-manager

I installed the application with apt and the first time app running well. I have connected my usb modem huawei e320 and works. the application showed me the sms and when i tried to click to see it, breaks and close.

My linux version:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I was tried to start from terminal and shows me this message:

```
~$ modem-manager-gui
Connection manager: Network Manager >= 0.9.0
Modem manager: Modem Manager >= 0.7.0

** (modem-manager-gui:3907): WARNING **: Modem Manager >= 0.7.0: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.79" (uid=1000 pid=3907 comm="modem-manager-gui ") interface="org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.Contacts" member="GetCount" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=727 comm="/usr/sbin/ModemManager ")
Segmentation fault at address: 0x30
Stack trace:
1. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xc2641) [0x7f5c2b194641]
2. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xc2641) [0x7f5c2b194641]
3. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(strftime_l+0x16) [0x7f5c2b196676]
4. modem-manager-gui(mmgui_str_format_sms_time+0xe7) [0x411b87]
5. modem-manager-gui() [0x42cdb0]
6. modem-manager-gui(mmgui_main_sms_list_fill+0x306) [0x42f226]
7. modem-manager-gui() [0x438450]
8. modem-manager-gui(mmguicore_devices_open+0x149) [0x421879]
9. modem-manager-gui(mmgui_main_device_select_from_list+0x10a) [0x430d8a]
```

and with sudo:

```
$ sudo modem-manager-gui
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Command line option parsing failed: Cannot open display:
```

---

Also I tried to start modemmanager and display:

```
~$ sudo ModemManager
ModemManager[6476]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.4.12) starting in system bus...
ModemManager[6476]: <warn>  Could not acquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1' service name
ModemManager[6476]: <info>  ModemManager is shut down
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: modem manager GUI 0.0.18,

Comment: ModemManager 1.4.12

Comment: Try to remove both and re-install again. I suspect some incompatible packages have been installed. Also try using a new user to test